# One domain - two servers in different countries

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

For example, I have a domain - "gog.com". And I wonna some customers from one country - be serviced by one server, and anothers by another server. Is it possible, without changing domain name?

Comment: When you say servers, do you mean web servers?

Comment: I mean different IPs and different datacenters and different servers. Yes, its web servers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a GeoIP service such as http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location to find the user's location and redirect them to their local server. If you use URL masking on your domain name they'll not see the redirection.

Comment: what do you mean redirect? "URL Masking the Domain Forwarding server sends the client a Frames page where the Frame Source contains the destination URL you have specified" - if this is what you saying, than its not accepted solution((

Answer (score 1):

As Khal suggested, you can use a GeoIP service to detect the users origin and then redirect them to their appropriate server. One option might be to have three server names www.gog.com, www.region1.gog.com and www.region2.gog.com. Requests hitting www.gog.com are redirected based on their origin to either www.region1.gog.com or www.region2.gog.com (with the redirection being indicated to the browser). This way, you'll need to do the redirection only on the first request and all subsequent requests can directly be served from the appropriate server.